# vCenter ghost network

Tags: networking, vmware-vcenter

I have 3 ESXi 6.5 hosts with the same network configuration: single Standard Switch with four networks with same naming on all hosts. This is what I see at ESXi web client.

Inside vCenter I see another four networks with different names (their names suggest that these names were used some time ago). Each of them is attached to a single VM and no host. Is it possible to delete them somehow? The reason why I am asking is that I tried to deploy vSphere Integrated Containers, but with no luck. The wizzard [hangs on Network tab](https://github.com/vmware/vic-ui/issues/625).